# wxPython Installer "directory not found"

Tags: python, user-interface, installation, wxpython

I'm installing wxPython on my computer. (32-bit python 2.7)
The application prompts me `"Setup will install wxPython3.0-py27 into the following folder. To continue, click Next. If you would like to select a different folder, click Browse."`

The "following folder" says H:\ ... \site-packages.
I do not have anything in the H drive.

When I click Browse and change the installation folder, everything installs fine until the it installs the last files, when it prompts me the following:

```
*displays "following folder before I click Browse"*
An error occurred while trying to create a file in the destination directory:
Setup was unable to create the directory "H:\*folder*".
Error 3: The system cannot find the path specified.
Click Retry to try again, Ignore to skip this file (not recommended), or Abort to cancel installation.
```

Retry brings up the same prompt, Abort cancels installation, and Ignore messes up everything after it finishes installation.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Where is Python 2.7 installed on your computer?

Comment: It is installed in `C:\Programs`, which is also where I want to install wxPython (in the same folder as Python)

Comment: I don't think putting Python stuff below C:\Programs is a good idea.  That location is/should be locked and files should not be created/added on the fly.  Python is compiling files on the fly and therefore creates new ones on the fly, I would put it to e.g. "c:\python27" and then install wxPython below it, you can then also have e.g. "c:\python34" etc side be side.